# Tizen binary file type and creation

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to create a Tizen app for the Samsung Gear S2.  For submission of the app I need to provide a binary.  What file type is the binary?  Is it `.tpk` or `.wgt`?  How to I force the Tizen IDE to create this output file?

Comment: It depends on type of project you have created.

tpk - When you create a native app(project).
wgt - When you create a Web App(HTML5, CSS, JS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to generate the binary(tpk/wgt).

1. Open Tizen SDK
2. Right Click on your project in Project Explorer3.

**If Web App**

3. Then click on '**Build Package**' which will generate the **wgt** file at .../workspace/projectname/

**If Native App**

3. Then click on 'Build Package' -> 'TPK' which will generate **tpk** at .../workspace/projectname/Debug

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official developer documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/distribution/binary)

> The Content Type of a binary is automatically detected and displayed [...]

In this context, several *Tizen* binary types exist:

1. Native (Wearable-Intergrated) -  `*.tpk` - Integrated
2. Native (Wearable-Linked) -   `*.tpk` - Linked
3. Web (Wearable-Integrated) -  `*.wgt` - Integrated
4. Web (Wearable-Linked) -  `*.wgt` - Linked
5. Web (Wearable-Standalone) -  `*.wgt` - Standalone

Thus, to create a binary of your *Tizen* project you have to configure all supported target devices and all other project properties according to the developer guide (see [link](https://developer.tizen.org/distribution/binary#Binary%20File)). Then:

> if saving is properly processed after the [Save] button is clicked, the information of the uploaded binary are automatically detected from the `manifest.xml` or `config.xml` file.

Hope it helps.